# Angular 2 Cli: ng serve error

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have created new Angular 2 application with angular-cli like this: `ng new PROJECT_NAME`
But when I run `ng serve` , it displays this error:

`Error: Attempting to watch missing directory: typings` ...

`broccoli plugin was instantiated at:` ....

Answer (score 6):

You should install typings package:
`npm install typings --global`

and than run following command:

`npm run postinstall`

Answer (score 2):

Postinstall is a process that needs to take place after npm installs all the required packages through. On some systems it does not take place.
To force it to install run the following commands in the project directory:

npm i -g typings

npm run postinstall

After running these you can easily launch ng serve in the project directory

Answer (score -1):

proxy issue maybe use
create a file in your root folde

```
{
    proxy=http://ip-addres:port
    "rejectUnauthorized": false
}
```